# Login & Register & Custom details WITHOUT plugin

Tags: custom-field, login, advanced-custom-fields, user-registration

I'm building a website in wordpress, and I need to make a login page & register page / popup with ajax + account page with some custom fields that I need to put thier like adress, phone number, etc...

I want to make that without any plugins - Can someone give me a tutorial or small explaination how to make it? how to start?

PS - I know PHP SQL in high level - without wordpress I would build that easily, I just need a small help how to make that in wordpress system

Thanks for all :)

Comment: Here's someone that had a similar question - they basically wanted to custom style the WordPress default screens (like login & register) - you can do all of this with custom templates directly in your theme: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/365154/theme-or-style-wordpress-message-pages/365159#365159

Answer (score 1):

I am doing the same thing at the moment and I just use the standard WP login/register systems/pages.

You can use [wp_signon()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_signon/) to do logon.

Then on a standard page, you can create a custom template and use this for retrieving their info: [wp_get_current_user()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user)

You will also need to get the customer user meta information you store too using: [get_user_meta()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta)

Hope that helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

for find out and init actions

```
if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
    add_action('init', 'ajax_login_init');
} else {
    add_action('init', 'ajax_logout_init');
}
function ajax_login_init()
{
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_login', 'ajax_login');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_register', 'ajax_register');
}
function ajax_logout_init()
{
    add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_logout', 'ajax_logout');
}
```

login function

```
function ajax_login()
{
    check_ajax_referer('ajax-login-nonce', 'security');
    $info = array();
    $info['user_login'] = $_POST['login_username'];
    $info['user_password'] = $_POST['login_password'];
    $info['remember'] = $_POST['remember'];

    $user_signon = wp_signon($info, false);
    if (is_wp_error($user_signon)) {
        wp_send_json(array('status' => 0, 'message' => $user_signon->get_error_message()));
    } else {
        wp_send_json(array('status' => 1, 'message' => __('you currectly logined')));;
    }
}
```

register function

```
function ajax_register()
{
    check_ajax_referer('ajax-register-nonce', 'security');
    // Post values
    $username = sanitize_text_field($_POST['register_username']);
    $password = sanitize_text_field($_POST['register_password']);
    $email = sanitize_text_field($_POST['register_email']);
    $name = sanitize_text_field($_POST['register_name']);
    $nick = sanitize_text_field($_POST['register_name']);

    $userdata = array(
        'user_login' => $username,
        'user_pass' => $password,
        'user_password' => $password,
        'user_email' => $email,
        'first_name' => $name,
        'nickname' => $nick,
    );

    $user_id = wp_insert_user($userdata);

    // add user meta
    $custom_user_meta_value = 'custom_user_meta_value';
    add_user_meta( $user_id, 'custom_user_meta', $custom_user_meta_value);

    // Return
    if (!is_wp_error($user_id)) {
        $user_signon = wp_signon($userdata, false);
        if (!is_wp_error($user_signon)) {
            wp_send_json(array('status' => 2, 'message' => __('your registration is successfuled and logined.')));
        } else {
            wp_send_json(array('status' => 1, 'message' => __('your registration is successfuled and logined')));
        }
    } else {
        wp_send_json(array('status' => 0, 'message' => __($user_id->get_error_message())));
    }
}
```

logout function

```
function ajax_logout()
{
    check_ajax_referer('ajax-logout-nonce', 'ajaxsecurity');

    wp_logout();
    ob_clean(); // probably overkill for this, but good habit
    echo 'adios!!';
    wp_die();
}

add_action('wp_logout', 'auto_redirect_after_logout');
function auto_redirect_after_logout()
{
    wp_redirect(home_url());
    exit();
}
```

Comment: You should try and explain the code you're providing.  I know what all the functions you've supplied are supposed to do, but you haven't really explained anything to the user who specified that they don't know WP that well.